# Addressing instance of custom class created in MS Office Application from outside (e.g. by VB Script)

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Imagine this:

Excel ("C:\file.xlsm") application environment holds the class module `MyClass` which looks like:

```
Public myInt As Integer
```

In this application environment I initialize the object and set value to `myInt` variable (not using property for simplification):

```
Set instanceOfMyClass = New MyClass
instanceOfMyClass.myInt = 22
```

Then I run something in VBScript, which when finished should change the value of `instanceOfMyClass.myInt` in the Excel application. I can get to the `application` object in VBScript like this:

```
Set XlApp = GetObject("C:\file.xlsm").Application
```

I know I could just set some cell value to the value I want like this:

```
XlApp.Range("file.xlsm!TheRange").Value = 33
```

and then through `Worksheet_Change` event in Excel application catch this value and assign it as new value of `instanceOfMyClass.myInt`, but I would like to know if there is a way to directly reference `instanceOfMyClass.myInt`.

Just for clarification, I need to use VBScript in this case, as I can run any number of vbs instances in parallel, which I can't in Excel application.

EDIT:
My question can be translated like:

Is there a place within Excel.Application object structure where the application stores instances of objects and so they are callable? Something like:

`Excel.Application.GetInstanceOfObjectByVariableName("instanc‌​eOfMyClass").myInt`

Comment: Office class modules can only be accessed by office. Office classes have two properties of instancing (unlike full program's classes which have more). Private or Public Not Creatable. The second means if you can create it you can give to VBS, but VBS can't create it. EG In Excel the Font object is Public Non Creatable - you can only get a font object by making a method call on another object like the Document object.

Comment: See if the VBProject object in Excel can access your class.

Comment: This is more like about accessing "object instance" of class, not creating it. And exactly as you point with the Font object. My question can be translated as. Is there a place within Excel.Application object structure where the application stores instances of objects and so they are callable? Like:

Excel.Application.GetInstanceOfObjectByVariableName("instanceOfMyClass").myInt

?

Comment: Not to my knowledge but you may be able to use VBProject (if you can't use the VBA editor) to call your VBScript. VBScript CAN be publically created allowing Excel to call your script passing your object as a parameter. See Windows Script Components - *Windows® Script Components provide you with an easy way to create powerful, reusable COM components in script. You create script components using any scripting language that supports the Microsoft® ActiveX® Scripting interfaces.*